# Equivalent for "ModelMetadata.IsComplexType" using Reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection, modelmetadata

I'm trying to use `System.Reflection` to get the same result for a property as with using the `metadata`, specifically the `IsComplexType` property. The problem that I'm facing is that I couldn't find the logic that MVC Framework uses to determine if a property is complex or not. The only features of a *complex type* I could find is that it is a class and [is not a built in type of the .Net framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata.iscomplextype%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). How can I determine if a (property)type is considered as a complex one, without using the `ModelMetadata` properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*IsComplexType* is implemented in the following way:

```
!TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(this.ModelType).CanConvertFrom(typeof(string));
```

All these classes are not specific for MVC and can be used by you. You only need to replace `ModelType` with a type you want to test.